# Python Logging, 'KeyError: context'

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, keyerror

I'm trying to setup child logging for a module, let's call it `child_module`, inside another `parent_module`.

In `parent_module` I'm calling the `child_module` like this:

```
class ParentModule(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 logger,
                 child_module=None):
        self.logger = logger

        # set-up the child module
        self.child_module = child_module

        if child_module is None:
            self.child_module = ChildModule(
                logger=logging.getLogger('log.parent_module.child_module')
            )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Configure logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger('log.parent_module')
    logger.setLevel(5)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    p = ParentModule(logger=logger)
```

Where log is the root log base. In the child_module, the **main** function is identical except the we are defining the log as `log.child_module`.
When I run this, I get the following traceback:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 547, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'context'
```

I cannot find anything about the 'context' variable that's supposed to be present in the Logging module and I am not defining any custom logged vars myself.

Comment: That looks very much like there is an active formatter somewhere in your execution context that tries to replace a placeholder named `context`. The following should show you all active format strings: `lgrs = {'root': logging.getLogger('')}`,  `lgrs.update(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)`, `print("\n".join(["logger: {}, format:{}".format(n[0], n[1]) for n in[(k, [h.formatter._fmt for h in v.handlers if h.formatter is not None]) for k,v in lgrs.items()]]))`. Maybe this helps finding out which logger uses it and where it is configured.